# How to parse data from time period to periodic time series with Pandas

Tags: pandas

I'm currently trying to parse data, which is given with a start and end date, from one dataframe to a second dataframe, which has a periodic timedateindex.
df1 is my input dataframe and I would like to parse it to df2-structure.
Actually I don't need the values itself, I just want to mark the period where they occur.

### df1

```
   Start             End               Value1  Value2
1  2018-01-02 15:20  2018-01-02 19:50  x       Nan
2  2018-03-21 05:40  2018-03-22 11:20  a       b
3  ...
```

---

### df2

```
                  Value1  Value2
2018-01-02 15:10  False   False
2018-01-02 15:20  True    False
2018-01-02 15:30  True    False
2018-01-02 15:40  True    False
...
2018-01-02 19:50  True    False
2018-01-02 20:00  False   False
```

I got already the structure for df2, but I couldn't figure out how to transform the data.

```
date_rng=pd.date_range(start='2018-01-01', end='2018-12-31', freq='10min')
df2=pd.DataFrame(date_rng, columns=['Date'])
df2['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Date'])
df2 = df2.set_index('datetime')
df2.drop(['Date'], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Anyone can help?
many thanks

Comment: Is df2 the expected output?

Comment: Yes, df2 is the desired output.

Comment: Why is Value2 always false in df2? Could you name your columns something like 'Value1IsX' and 'Value2IsB' to be specific about what the True and False are saying? I'm a bit confused as to how these values are determined. I understand if it is out of the range of dates for all rows then the value must be False, but I don't understand how the Value1 column can have a True when Value2 has a False.

Comment: but a value for Value2 is present for all values when Value1 is present (according to df1). Does Value2 need to equal something other than `y` for it to be True?

Comment: As mentioned in the first paragraph I'm not looking for the values of Value1 and Value2. I just want to assess, when a value is present.
So the Boolean values are just indicating the presence of the value for this timetamp.

Comment: Sry, you are right, Jack. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

You could initialize df2 with all values set to False and then iterate through both dataframes and checking if the time in df2 is within one/ore more of the specified intervals in df1.

Here a working example:

```
# | create some dummy data
data = [{'Start': '2018-01-02 15:20', 'End': '2018-01-02 19:50', 'Value1': 'x', 'Value2': np.nan},
        {'Start': '2018-01-01 00:00:00', 'End': '2018-01-01 00:15:00', 'Value1': 'a', 'Value2': np.nan}]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)
df1['Start'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Start'])
df1['End'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['End'])

date_rng=pd.date_range(start='2018-01-01', end='2018-12-31', freq='10min')
df2=pd.DataFrame(date_rng, columns=['Date'])
df2['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Date'])
df2 = df2.set_index('Date', drop=True)

# | initialize all values with False
df2['Value1'] = False
df2['Value2'] = False

# | iterate through dataframes (also check if values are NaN)
for _, row_1 in df1.iterrows():
    for index_2, row_2 in df2.iterrows():
        if not pd.isnull(row_1['Value1']):
            row_2['Value1'] = row_1['Start'] <= index_2 and row_1['End'] >= index_2
        if not pd.isnull(row_1['Value2']):
            row_2['Value2'] = row_1['Start'] <= index_2 and row_1['End'] >= index_2
```

## output:

```
                    Value1  Value2
Date        
2018-01-01 00:00:00 True    False
2018-01-01 00:10:00 True    False
2018-01-01 00:20:00 False   False
2018-01-01 00:30:00 False   False
.
.
.
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, nkaenzig.
It does what it sould do, but it's far too slow.
There must be a faster solution.